# How can I pipe a tar compression operation to aws s3 cp?

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, pipe, aws-sdk, tar

I'm writing a custom backup script in bash for personal use. The goal is to compress the contents of a directory via tar/gzip, split the compressed archive, then upload the parts to AWS S3.

On my first try writing this script a few months ago, I was able to get it working via something like:

```
tar -czf - /mnt/STORAGE_0/dir_to_backup | split -b 100M -d -a 4 - /mnt/SCRATCH/backup.tgz.part
aws s3 sync /mnt/SCRATCH/ s3://backups/ --delete
rm /mnt/SCRATCH/*
```

This worked well for my purposes, but required `/mnt/SCRATCH` to have enough disk space to store the compressed directory. Now I wanted to improve this script to not have to rely on having enough space in `/mnt/SCRATCH`, and did some research. I ended up with something like:

```
tar -czf - /mnt/STORAGE_0/dir_to_backup | split -b 100M -d -a 4 --filter "aws s3 cp - s3://backups/backup.tgz.part" -
```

This almost works, but the target filename on my S3 bucket is not dynamic, and it seems to just overwrite the `backup.tgz.part` file several times while running. The end result is just one 100MB file, vs the intended several 100MB files with endings like `.part0001`.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when using `split` you can use the env variable `$FILE` to get the generated file name.
See [split man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html):

```
--filter=COMMAND
     write to shell COMMAND; file name is $FILE
```

For your use case you could use something like the following:

```
--filter 'aws s3 cp - s3://backups/backup.tgz.part$FILE'
```

(the single quotes are needed, otherwise the environment variable substitution will happen immediately)

Which will generate the following file names on aws:

```
backup.tgz.partx0000
backup.tgz.partx0001
backup.tgz.partx0002
...
```

Full example:

```
tar -czf - /mnt/STORAGE_0/dir_to_backup | split -b 100M -d -a 4 --filter 'aws s3 cp - s3://backups/backup.tgz.part$FILE' -
```

Comment: This worked! I actually did try using the $FILE variable after reading a bit more, but I was using double quotes to contain my aws command, so I thought $FILE had issues with accepting data from a pipe. Changing to single quotes did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get it done quite easily and in parallel using **GNU Parallel**. It has the `--pipe` option to split the input data into blocks of size `--block` and distribute it amongst multiple parallel processes.

So, if you want to use 100MB blocks and use all cores of your CPU in parallel, and append the block number (`{#}`) to the end of the filename on AWS, your command would look like this:

```
tar czf - something | parallel --pipe --block 100M --recend '' aws s3 cp - s3://backups/backup.tgz.part{#}
```

You can use just 4 CPU cores instead of all cores with `parallel -j4`.

Note that I set the *"record end"* character to nothing so that it doesn't try to avoid splitting mid-line which is its default behaviour and better suited to text file processing than binary files like tarballs.

Comment: `--bar` is incompatible with `--pipe`. This is because `--bar` needs to know how many jobs there are in total, and it would therefore have to read everything from the `--pipe` to do that - which will often defeat the purpose of `--pipe`.